# URL for container directory associated with application group identifier is nil on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been trying to figure out why this is happening for at least a full working day now.

The following code returns the correct url on my machine (both simulator and device), but it returns `nil` on a machine that is set up to run for CI (the identifier is different but that is irrelevant):

```
let containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.my.example.app"
```

I've already confirmed the following:

1. App Groups is enabled in entitlements.
2. The same app group identifier is defined in the code and entitlements.
3. The provisioning profile is up to date and has the same app group identifier associated with it.
4. My machine and the one used to run CI use different certificates but both are added to the provisioning profile.
5. I'm using automatic code signing.
6. I've tried resetting the simulator – no success.

The weirdest thing is that the correct url is returned when I run the app on the CI machine on a real device instead of the simulator. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Edit 1: App trying to run the app on iPhone 7, iOS 12.0 simulator, but the same happens on iOS 11.3 simulator.